# What does bquote do in this example using mgcv::gam in a function

Tags: r, mgcv

in the following function I have to use the bquote function when fitting the gam model to avoid the error

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found

when plot.gam is called. The error occurs due to the factor variable I want to plot. However I don't really understand what the bquote does here and why I need it.

```
library(mgcv)
plot_model <- function(x){
  # agam <- gam(mean ~ s(bla) + bla2, data=x)
  agam <- eval(bquote(mgcv::gam(mean ~ s(bla) + bla2, data=.(x))))
  plot(agam, pages=1, all.terms = TRUE)
}
bla <- data.frame(bla=rnorm(20), bla2=sample(letters[1:4], size=20, replace=T), 
                  mean=sample(20))

plot_model(bla)
```

The R-help says "bquote quotes its argument except that terms wrapped in .() are evaluated in the specified where environment. Usage bquote(expr, where = parent.frame())." What is the where environment here (parent.frame = the plot_model environment?) and what environment would it be evaluated in without the bquote (the environment created by the call to gam?)?

Answer (score 0):

`bquote` substitutes the expression `.(X)` with the value of `x`. Therefore what is actually evaluated is:

```
mgcv::gam(mean ~ s(bla) + bla2, data = list(bla = c(-0.147370861075094, <...>)
```

This error pops up because `plot.gam` asks to look for the symbol `x` in the global environment rather than the environment of `plot_model`.

When debugged with `recover`:

```
<...>
3: plot.gam(agam, pages = 1, all.terms = TRUE)
4: termplot(x, se = se, rug = rug, col.se = 1, col.term = 1, main = attr(x$pterms, "term.
5: eval(model$call$data, envir)
<...>
Browse[1]> envir
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

Comment: but even using bquote x isn't in the global environment, is it?

Comment: Unlike `plot.gam`, `bquote` looks for `x` in the **current** environment, i.e. `plot_model(x = bla)`. You pass `bla` to `plot_model` as an argument `x`, so `x` is only accessible from within that environment (and its descentants). But, as you can see in my example, when you use expression `.(x)` with `bquote`, the symbol `x` is replaced with its value.

Comment: But how does that explain that plot.gam finds x when gam is called using bquote? gam would work without bquote, it's plot that only works with bquote. Why is x suddenly available for plot after estimating the gam with bquote?

Comment: To understand this you need to familiarize yourself with the concept of R expressions. An expression can be seen as an unevaluated piece of code (though it is not the same as character string). In your example, you do two things: first expand the expression from `gam(..., data=x)` to `gam(..., data=list(bla=..., bla2=))` (note it is still a *code* at this stage), next, you evaluate this modified expression (in which there is no longer `x` present) using `eval`.

Comment: BTW this is clearly a bug in `plot.gam` and so should be reported to **mgcv**'s maintainer.